# Android Activity Splash Screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a splash screen which displays for 2-3 sec before it disappears.
I want to add a Fade in Effect when the next activity is loaded. I saw an Example in the Facebook Hacker Example and i am using it.
It uses a finish(); to end that activity to so from the DashboardActivity if some one clicks back it doesnt return back to the SplashAcitivty. But using this doesnt create the Fade in Effect as show in the API demos Examples.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    private long splashDelay = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Remove notification bar
        /*
         * this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
         * WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
         */

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent().setClass(SplashActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade, R.anim.hold);
            }
        };

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, splashDelay);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a handler for this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                MainActivity.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade, R.anim.hold);
        finish();
    }
}, splashDelay);
```

Comment: Awesome :D thanks a lot :D can you please explain how this works. Does it run a background thread ?

Comment: `TimerTask` runs on a background thread. `Handler` executes the `Runnable` on the UI thread, which is what you need, because you want to update the UI.